# Extract string that is delimited with constant and ends with two numbers (numbers have to be included)

Tags: python, regex

I have a text that contains string of a following structure:

```
text I do not care about, persons name followed by two IDs.
```

I know that:

- a person's name is always preceded by `XYZ` code and that is always followed by
  two, space separated numbers.
- `Name` is not always just a last name and first name. It can be multiple last or first names
  (think Latin american names).

So, I am looking to extract string that follows the constant `XYZ` code and that is always terminated by two separate numbers.

You can say that my delimiter is `XYZ` and two numbers, but numbers need to be part of the extracted value as well.

From

> blah, blah XYZ names, names 122322 344322 blah blah

I want to extract:

> names, names 122322 344322

Would someone please advise on the regular expression for this that would work with Python's re package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(?<=XYZ\s)(\w[^\d]+\d+\s\d+)`

where your names and numbers `(\w[^\d]+\d+\s\d+)` are preceded by `XYZ`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: @mishik - thanks for the feedback, still new to SO. to clarify, was it about the wording of the response or the pattern?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex

```
(?<=XYZ\s+)[a-zA-Z\s,]+\d+\s+\d+
---------- ----------  ---------
     |         |          |->matches two numbers separated by space
     |         |->matches names separated by ,
     |->lookbehind assertion which checks for a XYZ followed by space before matching the string
```

Comment: In python, this one reported: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern

Answer (score 0):

You can try this pattern:

```
 r"(?<=XYZ )(?:[a-z'-]+,? )+\d+ \d+"
```

the result is the whole match.